# Recording a Data Entry Time: modify my macro to make it valid for multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel, timestamp

I found a macro online that automatically inputs the date in column B (row X), if the content of column A (same row) is altered.

I would like to modify it so that it works on multiple rows - so that in addition to monitoring changes in row A, it will do the same for columns C, E, G, and input dates in columns D, F, H (respectively) if the former's content is changed.

Here's the macro I found, from: http://excel.tips.net/T003116_Recording_a_Data_Entry_Time.html

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rChange As Range

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set rChange = Intersect(Target, Range("A:A"))
    If Not rChange Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each rCell In rChange
            If rCell > "" Then
                With rCell.Offset(0, 1)
                    .Value = Now
                    .NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
                End With
            Else
                rCell.Offset(0, 1).Clear
            End If
        Next
    End If

ExitHandler:
    Set rCell = Nothing
    Set rChange = Nothing
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

---

I'm not too familiar with all the different VBA elements, so forgive the elementary question. Hope you can take the time to help, thanks.

Comment: Sorry - forgot to mention that part. I tried changing Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) to Intersect(Target, Range("A:A", "C:C", "E:E"))

But then not even the original column A time-stamp worked...kind of a naive attempt by my part... I'm new to VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
Set rChange = Intersect(Target, Range("A:A"))
```

with:

```
Set rChange = Intersect(Target, Range("A:A, C:C, E:E, G:G"))
```

Comment: That worked" Thanks GS! I had put the column ranges in individual quotation marks rathern than put them all within one set of quotation marks. Much appreciated.